# SQL server 2012 performance issue against sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

We migrated our DB from sql server 2008 r2 to sql server 2012. We have a big stored procedure which use more than 15 tables to populated data. This stored procedure was taking just 1 second in previous server which has very low resources (24 GB ram 1 ghz processor). New server which have sql server 2012 installed (this server has near about 10X high resources) is executing same stored procedure in 10 seconds. When I checked the execution plan in this server, it is displaying many warning for type conversion. Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a SQL server 2012 expert, but corresponding to [pages about conversion warnings](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/07/identifying-correcting-sql-server-implicit-conversion/)
the problem is that you may have columns in different tables, that are used as join keys, but don't have the same type. E.g. table1.categoryId as int and table2.categoryId as varchar and a join on both of this columns. SQL server seems to do an implicit conversion (int to varchar or otherwise), which is a performance killer.

Corresponding to [this page](http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/blogs/AmitBansal/sql-server-bi/369/sql-server-2012-denali-execution-plan-warnings-part-1) this also can happen, when you use different datatypes in your query. For example when you have table1.postalcode as int and use `SELECT * from table1 where postalcode in ('123', '234')`. Here the values in the IN-Clause would be strings, while the table-row is int.

The solution would be changing the types of the rows and migrating your data to the new tables.